# Combine multiple textbox text into a string in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to do a program for the user to key in IP addresses. I created 4 text box and user will key in 3 numbers to each text box. In the end I need to combine this 4 text box so that it can become a valid IP address. This IP address will put into a string so that I can send it through serial port. How do we do it?

Comment: Provide an example, clearly explaining the problem/ scenarios.

Comment: I've tried this:textBox2.Text.CopyTo(IpAddress, 0);
                textBox20.Text.CopyTo(IpAddress, 3);
                textBox21.Text.CopyTo(IpAddress, 6);
                textBox22.Text.CopyTo(IpAddress, 9); but fail

Comment: Yes. I'm very new in c#. Hope you guys can help me.

Comment: You really should read tutorials for new users rather than post questions about extremely simple operations in C#. I mean, assuming your long term plan isn't to post a question for every line of code you ever write.

Comment: Why do you want them in an array? it should be single string containing value. For example, 10.253.11.10. This you can get this in a string variable.

Comment: Sorry guys actually it's not combined into an array. I want to combine it into a string. How do we do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to concatenate the strings...

```
var strIP = tb1.Text + '.' + tb2.Text + '.' + tb3.Text + '.' + tb4.Text;
//This is to see it
MessageBox.Show(strIP);
```

Or you can use a StringBuilder....

```
var strIP = new StringBuilder();
strIP.Append(tb1.Text);
strIP.Append('.');
strIP.Append(tb2.Text);
strIP.Append('.');
strIP.Append(tb3.Text);
strIP.Append('.');
strIP.Append(tb4.Text);

//This is to see it
MessageBox.Show(strIP.ToString());
```

Answer (score 4):

```
String.Join(".",tb1.Text, tb2.Text, tb3.Text, tb4.Text)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
IPAddress ipaddress = IPAddress.Parse(tb1.Text + "." + tb3.Text + "." +tb3.Text + "." + tb4.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var ipArray = new [] {tb1.Text, tb2.Text, tb3.Text, tb4.Text}
```

Comment: Sorry guys actually it's not combined into an array. I want to combine it into a string. How do we do it?

Comment: Could you guys lift the ban on me... Give me another chance.